# python calling a subprocess that runs in parallel

Tags: python, subprocess, parallel-processing

I have code that calls a commercial program to run as a subprocess using the subprocess module.

The commercial program is capable of running in parallel, but I have noticed that only 1 processor is being used when the subprocess is running.

Is there a simple way to run a serial python program that requests more resources, for example 4 processors, for the subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

If the subprocess is really capable of multicore operation, it shouldn't matter how you spawn it. You don't (and generally, can't) "request" more cores for it -- the OS will automatically give it whatever resources are available.

I suspect the answer lies with the commercial program in question rather than with the parent process, Python or the `subprocess` package.